# xCode: How can you detect if a user has enabled your custom keyboard or has enabled open access?

Tags: xcode, keyboard, ios8

In iOS8 you now have the ability to create keyboard extensions. For some operations you need to request open access. How are you able to tell if a user has added your keyboard extension and if it has enabled full access?